# fetching monthwise data from a database with a year's record in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a table with a years data with the following columns:

```
Table "myData" ((
    "Status" character varying,  
    "Project" character varying,  
    "Product" character varying, 
    "Identifier" character varying, 
    "Submittedon" date
    )
```

etc.,

Now to fetch a count of records submitted on a particular month. Say like April 2013's Record count, I am using:

```
select count("Status") as April2013 
from "myData"  
where (
    "SubmittedOn" > (current_date - 90) 
    and "SubmittedOn" < (current_date - 60)
)
```

Result:

```
April2013
--------
62
```

Now my requirement is to fetch the count of records for the past 6 months. I mean i want my output in any of the below formats:

```
FORMAT 1:
```

[image]

```
FORMAT 2:

6MonthsCount
-------------
34

23

44

41

18

9
```

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: You tagged this both mysql and postgresql, which system do you use?

Comment: @lathspell Sorry it was a typo mistake. I am using Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    date_trunc('month', submittedOn) "month",
    count("Status") total
from "myData"  
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: @Clodaoldo Neto: Thanks..I am looking into your suggestion!!

Comment: @Clodaoldo Neto: Thank you once again, your solution helped me fix my problem!! :)

Comment: @Clodaoldo Neto: How to get the value as 0 for a month. When there is no entry for submittedOn column for a particular month..Right now..The month and value wont come...

Comment: @Deepak Check [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17471970/131874) or post another question.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a "Pivot"-Table so use the crosstab() function of the tablefunc extention
(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html):

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (status text, submitteton date);
INSERT INTO mydata VALUES ('a', '2013-01-02'), ('b', '2013-01-05'), ('c', '2013-02-09'), ('d', '2013-04-11');


SELECT extract(month from submitteton) as month, count(*) FROM mydata GROUP BY month;
 month | count 
-------+-------
     1 |     2
     2 |     1
     4 |     1

CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  crosstab(
    'SELECT 
       extract(year from submitteton)::int as year,
       extract(month from submitteton) as month, 
       count(*)::int 
     FROM
       mydata 
     GROUP BY 1,2 
     ORDER BY 1,2', 

     'SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 12)'
  ) as ct(
    year int,
    jan int, feb int, mar int, apr int, may int, jun int, 
    jul int, aug int, sep int, oct int, nov int, dec int
  )
ORDER BY 
  year
;

 year | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec 
------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 2013 |   2 |   1 |     |   1 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How to add one more filter to the count, I mean I do not want the entire count of records, I want records whose Status = "XYZ". Once again thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: I guess you can add a WHERE after the "FROM mydata"

Answer (score 1):

You ought to use intervals and date_trunc, rather than explicit numbers of days:

```
denis=# select date_trunc('month', now()) as d;
           d            
------------------------
 2013-06-01 00:00:00+02
(1 row)

denis=# select date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '2 months' as d;
           d            
------------------------
 2013-04-01 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

To generate the past 6 months, use `generate_series()`:

```
denis=# select d as start, d + interval '1 month' as stop
        from generate_series(date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '6 month',
                             date_trunc('month', now()),
                             '1 month') d;
         start          |          stop          
------------------------+------------------------
 2012-12-01 00:00:00+01 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00+01
 2013-01-01 00:00:00+01 | 2013-02-01 00:00:00+01
 2013-02-01 00:00:00+01 | 2013-03-01 00:00:00+01
 2013-03-01 00:00:00+01 | 2013-04-01 00:00:00+02
 2013-04-01 00:00:00+02 | 2013-05-01 00:00:00+02
 2013-05-01 00:00:00+02 | 2013-06-01 00:00:00+02
 2013-06-01 00:00:00+02 | 2013-07-01 00:00:00+02
(7 rows)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

From there, a simple join with a count/group by will yield the expected result.

(Note: if you need timestamps without a timezone, replace `now()` with e.g. `(now() at time zone 'utc')::timestamp(0)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking into your suggestion. :)