# PostgreSQL incremental dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I have a database table that contains the following data:

```
ID | Date       | Bla
1  | 2013-05-01 | 1
2  | 2013-05-02 | 2
3  | 2013-05-03 | 3
4  | 2013-05-05 | 4
```

Note that there is a date missing: `2014-05-04`. How should I alter the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
where DATE >= '2013-05-01' AND DATE <= '2013-05-05'
```

So that I would end up with the following output:

```
ID   | Date       | Bla
1    | 2013-05-01 | 1
2    | 2013-05-02 | 2
3    | 2013-05-03 | 3
null | 2013-05-04 | null
4    | 2013-05-05 | 4
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join with a `generate_series` output:

```
select
    '2013-05-01'::date + g.o AS "date with offset"
from
    generate_series(0, 30) AS g(o)
```

Output:

```
"2013-05-01"
"2013-05-02"
"2013-05-03"
...
"2013-05-29"
"2013-05-30"
"2013-05-31"
```

Or... an easier method after defining a new stored procedure :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_series(date, date) RETURNS
SETOF date AS $$
SELECT $1 + g.s
FROM generate_series(0, ($2 - $1)) AS g(s);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Just call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(start_date, end_date);
```

Comment: How can this be used if you only have a start and end date?

Comment: Use something like this: `generate_series(0, (end_date - start_date)::integer`)`

Comment: As long as you're on Postgres 8.4 or higher, you don't need to define a custom `generate_series` function, as there's a native [`generate_series(from_timestamp, to_timestamp, step_interval)` variant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) (just use `'1 day'::interval` as the step in this case).

Comment: Sorry for the edit but that long list was really annoying me :)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: fair enough :)

Comment: @IMSoP: true, but this is more convenient to use imho since you don't need to cast anymore :)

Comment: @WoLpH `'1 day'::interval` isn't really a *cast* as such, just a typed literal. Of course, you could define `generate_series(date, date)` as `SELECT g.s FROM generate_series($1, $2, '1 day'::interval) AS g(s);` if you really dislike typing the extra parameter.

Comment: @IMSoP: true, but not having to think about the types always makes me feal slightly more at ease, it's just a mental thing I suppose...

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from 
    (
        select generate_series(
            '2013-05-01'::date, '2013-05-05', '1 day'
            )::date
    ) s("date")
    left join
    t using ("date")
```

Replace both `"date"` with the actual column name.

Comment: +1 It's the best code. But some explanation and maybe a link to the manual for [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to outer join your table against a "list of dates":

```
with all_dates (some_date) as (
    select date '2013-05-01' + i 
    from generate_series(0, 10) i  -- adjust here to the range of dates you need.
) 
select t.id, 
       ad.some_date, -- you need to take the actual date from generated ones
       t.bla
from all_dates ad
  left join the_table t on ad.some_date = t.date
where ad.some_date between date '2013-05-01' and date '2013-05-05';
```

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. Apart from the fact that it is a reserved word it also tells nothing about what kind of "date" that is.

Comment: As shown in Clodoaldo Neto's answer, `generate_series` can create a series of dates natively, simplifying the CTE somewhat, and making it easier to remove the `WHERE` clause completely in favour of a properly chosen date range in the CTE. Nicely laid out answer otherwise though.

Comment: Oh, and I would imagine `DATE` is an anonymised/example column name, since the table in the query is referred to as `TABLE`, which is an unlikely name for a table :)

Comment: @IMSoP a_horse sure knows about the `date` overload of `generate_series`. He is probably considering if the OP uses an older postgresql version with only the integer overload of `generate_series`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: to be honest: I always forget about the "date" version of generate_series() ;)

Comment: Regarding versioning, it's available since 8.4, which came out 4 years ago and is now the oldest "fully supported" version, so it's probably safe to assume it will be there now. :)